# Dynamic Paint object should be brush and canvas at the same time

Tags: particles, dynamic-paint

I have a ship that sails on the ocean in the rain. The ship is set as brush because it leaves a trail in the ocean. The raindrops that come down should now also leave a trace on the ship's deck with wetpaint. But because I have already set the ship as a brush, I can no longer set it as a canvas. Is it possible to set the ship as a brush and canvas at the same time? Many Thanks!

Comment: just copy the object and set one as brush and one as canvas. Or split it in that way, that the upper part is canvas for the raindrops and the lower part canvas for the ocean.

Comment: Yeah that could be a solution. But then in general it is not possible to do this with just one object,?

Comment: unfortunately not AFAIK. Blender just allows one dynamic paint modifier per object.

Comment: Hmm ok thanks then I'll try this later!

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is that you can see when 2 identical objects are exactly on top of each other. Then it seems to be white through something. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I would make the brush invisible. Should work.

Comment: How do you mean exactly? Because of the brush, I only created the second object. What I mean is that when 2 objects are exactly on top of each other it generally looks kind of weird white overlapping in Blender.

Comment: I understood what you mean. You didn’t understand what I mean. Try giving the brush a material with alpha = 0. hopefully the brush will still work, but not be visible. Then your problem is gone.

Comment: But the brush is not the problem. If I put 2 objects exactly on top of each other in Blender, they are always displayed a bit strange somehow. Even without Dynamic Paint. 
Somewhat whitish.

Comment: Once again: That’s why I wrote: make the brush invisible with material settings: alpha = 0

Comment: I'm sorry, but somehow I don't get it right. I took out Dynamic Paint completely, which is why there is no longer a brush at all. The Alpha setting is only intended for the Brush or it hadn't changed anything there. But no matter I think I'll do it now without the bouncing raindrops. 